# php jquery ajax jquery >than not working as it should

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form where is validated through the below code:

```
function add_to_cart(){
jQuery('#modal_errors').html("");
var quantity = jQuery('#quantity').val();
var available=jQuery('#available').val();
var error='';
var data = jQuery('#add_product_form').serialize();
if(quantity==''||quantity==0){
    error+='<p class="text-danger text-center">You must enter a quantity which is greater than 0!!! To set an order to 0 kindly visit your cart!!!</p>';
    jQuery('#modal_errors').html(error);
    return;
}else if(!(quantity < available)){
    error += '<p class="text-danger text-center">There are only '+available+' available, kindly enter a number equal or smeller than availability!!!</p>';
    jQuery('#modal_errors').html(error);
    return;
}else{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : '/aresV2/admin/parsers/add_cart.php',
        method : 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            location.reload();
            },
        error: function(){alert("something went wrong in cart parser!!");}
        });
}}
```

The else if statement

> ((!(quantity < available))) **NOTE** tried to make (quantity > available) but to no avail

is not working as it should as it is not accepting certain numbers to pass even though they are within the accepted range.

> Example Quantity is 2 and available is 12. Quantity 3 is seen as wrong (**which should not be seen wrong**), 1 is
>   seen as right (which is correct) and 13 as wrong (which is correct)

The below is the from where the jquery function is getting the data:

```
<form action="add_cart.php" method="post" data-toggle="validator" id="add_product_form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?= $id ;?>">

                            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['SBUser'])){ ?>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1"> 

                            </div><div class="col-xs-9"></div>
                                <p>Available: <?= $prodQty['ProdQTY'] ;?></p>
                                <!-- <p>Available: <?= $prodType ;?></p> -->
                            </div><br /><br />

                            <?php }else{
                                echo'<b>Kindly, login by clicking <a href="login.php"><u>here</u></a> to be able to add items to your shopping cart!!';

                            } ;?>


                            <input type="hidden" name="available" id="available" value="<?= $prodQty['ProdQTY'] ;?>">
                        </form>
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out it should work for you. jquery's `.val()` method returns string i.e `"5"` which misbehaves when you compare numbers.

```
function add_to_cart(){
    jQuery('#modal_errors').html("");
    var quantity = +jQuery('#quantity').val(); //added + to convert to number
    var available= +jQuery('#available').val();
    var error='';
    var data = jQuery('#add_product_form').serialize();
    if(quantity===0){
        error+='<p class="text-danger text-center">You must enter a quantity which is greater than 0!!! To set an order to 0 kindly visit your cart!!!</p>';
        jQuery('#modal_errors').html(error);
        return;
    }else if(quantity > available){
        error += '<p class="text-danger text-center">There are only '+available+' available, kindly enter a number equal or smeller than availability!!!</p>';
        jQuery('#modal_errors').html(error);
        return;
    }else{
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : '/aresV2/admin/parsers/add_cart.php',
            method : 'post',
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                location.reload();
                },
            error: function(){alert("something went wrong in cart parser!!");}
            });
    }}
```

Comment: Oh, I would have never thought that was the reason. THank you very much Manoj Yadav =]

Comment: just for fun  "5" < "12" returns false in javascript. where as  5<12 return true!!!! chears!

Comment: thanks again, was going nuts to solve but i never that part of the code =]